# website shows 500 code error after issuing 301-redirect

Tags: http-status-code-301

I have a long list of redirects, about 1300. Somewhere along these 1300 301-redirects something went wrong. Whenever I upload my .htaccess file I get a 500 code on my website.

I dont know how to show you guys the code as am not allowed to post more than 30k characters.

Any help or ideas is deeply appreciated.

```
redirect 301 /wp/baddsoffa-trento/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/golvlampa-bono/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/golvlampa-brooklyn/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/atlanta-hornsoffa-2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/hornsoffa-london-2h25/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/kandelaber-multi/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/kladhangare-knax-2-2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/knax-imperial/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/fatolj-fotpall-conto/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/ullmatta-glaze/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/spegel-rennes/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/ullmatta_chocolate/ http://www.living.se/ 
redirect 301 /wp/fatolj-anelo/ ‹http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/spegel-rochelle/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/goa-coffetable-distress-saj-1059d/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/soffbord-egg/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/spegel-nante/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/amadeus-lounge-chair-2/ http://www.living.se/ 
redirect 301 /wp/byra-nancy/http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/matbord-wasa/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /tokyo-3-sits-soffa/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/liggstol-movie/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/living-fyller-15-ar-3/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /matbord-ascona-2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /?variations=beige http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /vaggklocka-london-vintage/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /startsida/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /sortiment/soffor.html http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /stol-zipper/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/stolar/ 
redirect 301 /sangbord-striped/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/sovrum/
redirect 301 /pappelina-siri/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/galge-zitti-svart-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/accessories/
redirect 301 /wp/mobelvard-textilkit/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/mobelvard/
redirect 301 /wp/matbord-salto/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/
redirect 301 /wp/fatolj-therese/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/fatoljer/
redirect 301 /wp/vintage-lykta-40/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/belysning/
redirect 301 /plad-chenille-text/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/kuddar-pladar/
redirect 301 /wp/visible-mocca-ryamatta/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/mattor/
redirect 301 /plastmatta-pappelina-owen/page/2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/mattor/
redirect 301 /etikett/svartmalad/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/playsam/ http://www.living.se/ 
redirect 301 /wp/hallbank-point/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/hallmobler/
redirect 301 /wp/bohuslan/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /golvlampa-rebell/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/belysning/
redirect 301 /wp/soffa-lazy/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /wp/vagghangd-ljusstake/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/accessories/
redirect 301 /wp/soffbord-java/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffbord/
redirect 301 /wp/limhamn-60/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/byra-harlequin/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/forvaring/
redirect 301 /etikett/kontorsstol/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/stolar/
redirect 301 /wp/kategori/soffbord/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffbord/
redirect 301 /wp/kategori/india_collection/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tray-soffbord-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffbord/
redirect 301 /wp/kategori/ovrigt/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tradgardsset-capri/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/soffbord-kampanj/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/snurrfatolj-living/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/fatoljer/
redirect 301 /wp/fatolj-cayenne/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/fatoljer/
redirect 301 /wp/kategori/rea/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/rea/
redirect 301 /wp/sittpuff/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/fatoljer/
redirect 301 /wp/soffa-time-3a-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /wp/fatolj-chester/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/fatoljer/
redirect 301 /etikett/laminat/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/matbord-zata/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/ 
redirect 301 /wp/matbord-matrix/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/
redirect 301 /wp/trappstol-zitti-svart/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/stolar/
redirect 301 /wp/sommarmobel-santorini-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/outdoor/
redirect 301 /wp/black-jack-soffa/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/liniedesign/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/sangbord-striped/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/sovrum/
redirect 301 /wp/fatolj-manchester-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/fatoljer/
redirect 301 /wp/byra-cubio/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/forvaring/
redirect 301 /wp/stol-athen/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/stolar/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/lykta/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/belysning/
redirect 301 /wp/sidobord-marina/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/arctic-tv-bank-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/tv-mediabankar/
redirect 301 /wp/stol-hovdala-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/hylla/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/hallmobler/
redirect 301 /wp/lampbord-cabana/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/stol-bella/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/stolar/
redirect 301 /knax-turquoise/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/soffa-chelsea/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /wp/tv-bank-azzaro-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/tv-mediabankar/
redirect 301 /wp/kladhangare-knax-3/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/accessories/
redirect 301 /etikett/hallbank/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/hallmobler/
redirect 301 /wp/dekorations-tofs/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/nero/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/visible-silver-ryamatta/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/mator/
redirect 301 /fatolj-bern/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/fatoljer/
redirect 301 /wp/lyx-kakfat/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/byra/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/forvaring/
redirect 301 /wp/knax-summer/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/
redirect 301 /kladhangare-zitti-svart/page/2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/accessories/
redirect 301 /wp/skohylla-zitti-3/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/hallmobler/
redirect 301 /wp/matbord-saturn/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/
redirect 301 /wp/arctic-byra/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/forvaring/
redirect 301 /wp/lounge-soffa-3-divan/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /etikett/divan/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /wp/matbord-bono-atlantic/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/ 
redirect 301 /wp/soffa-largo-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/soffor/
redirect 301 /etikett/glas/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/accessories/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/matbord-2/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/
redirect 301 /plad/comment-page-1/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/kuddar-pladar/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/betong/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /arctic-grey-matta/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/mattor/
redirect 301 /etikett/pilasterhylla/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/hallmobler/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/hjellegjerde/ http://www.living.se/mobler-i-malmo/matbord/

redirect 301 /pappelina-alve/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /citybike-tavla/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /fatolj-havanna/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /slagbord-viggso/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /mediabank-base-135/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /vitrinskap-azzaro-3/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /mobler-i-malmo/outdoor/capri-delux-tradgardsstol-2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/knax-turquoise/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /weeb_slides/apollo-baddsoffa-nu-pa-lager/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /grapatinerade-ljusstakar-i-tra/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/anilinlader/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/vintage/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/kista/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wall-smal-bokhylla/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/kladhangare-zitti-2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/farskinn-massor-av-farger/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/bordslampa-diva/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/heaven-2-sits-soffa/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/dorrmatta/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /ullmatta-glaze/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /pappelina-lilo/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/hogblank/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/arctic-bedside/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/stol-birka/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/kub-2-lador-sa-3112/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/stol-oregon/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/ekfaner/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/kladhangare-zitti/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/sa-3117/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffa-largo/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /ullmatta-cos/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/alla-soffor-och-fatoljer/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /arctic-white-matta/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wall-smal-bokhylla/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /goa-louvre-sideboard-sa-6012/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffbord/lampbord-multe/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /nyheter/funktionsfatolj-tampa/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffbord-marocko/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /goa-reclaimed-trunk-sa-6006/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /pappelina-alve/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /fatboy-marimekko/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/troels/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /tavla-beatiful-flower/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /mobler-i-malmo/soffbord/louvre-reclaimed-trunk-sa-6006/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /tavla-beatiful-moment/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wall-bred-bokhylla/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /goa-soffbord-yo-236/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /fotpall-apollo/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /goa-louvre-plasma-cabinet-sa-6013/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /plenty-multi-matta/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffbord-limhan-90/feed/  http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /mobler-i-malmo/accessories/julhjarta-lilla/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /tag/hall/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /puff/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /reason-matbord/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/sommarmobel-riva/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/soffbord-fleur/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/fatolj-palma/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /mattor/plastmatta-pappelina-vera-one-5/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /voice-10/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /plastmatta-pappelina-vera-one-5/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/divansoffa-malta/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/forvaraing/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /belysning/golvlampa-edison/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/soffa-madrid/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tavlor/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /byra-saro/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffor/desiree-divansoffa-hoger/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/nightstand-harlequin/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /buffe-tokyo-black/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /brickbord/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/soffa-time-3a/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /tradgardsmobel-capri-de-luxe/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/nero/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/laderfatolj-lotus/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/forvaring-sa-3161/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/kategori/living_collection/page/2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffbord-2-drawers/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffor/bakhtiar-soffa-2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /accessories/julstjarna-110/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/filt/ http://www.living.se/ 
redirect 301 /wp/tag/skrivbord/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/mediabank/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/kategori/nyheter/page/3/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /arctic_azzaro/arctic-sliding-door/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/skrivbord/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /fatoljer/relax-liggfatolj-cerise/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/vitlack/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/hall/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/armbandsur-kyboe/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/vintage-lykta-1768/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/divansoffa-infinity/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/arctic-grey-matta/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /mobler-i-malmo/rea/bistro-stol-2-pack/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffor/tresitssoffa-mexico/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /knax-imperial/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /flash/sales.swf http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/lykat/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /visible-mocca-ryamatta/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /stol-toulouse/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/matbord-2/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /etikett/svart-ekfaner/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/vision-mediapanel/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /tavla-birds/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/ryamatta/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/wall/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /wp/tag/lykta/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /ovrigt/vintage-spegel/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /soffa-4sits-colorado/feed/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /mobler-i-malmo/hallmobler/havanna-sittbank-gron/ http://www.living.se/
redirect 301 /amadeus-lounge-chair/feed/ http://www.living.se/
```

Comment: Don't post the whole htaccess, just a relevant fragment. Moreover, trying to reduce it to the relevant fragment might already reveal what's wrong. With the info you're giving, we can only guess by consulting our crystal ball...

Comment: @GrimaceofDespair Yes I thought of that afterwards, I added some code, I think the problem should be there somewhere, not sure

Comment: You should really think about using rewrite maps for what you're doing, which will reduce the chance that you'll introduce a syntax error, just because you're manipulating the pages that needs redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jpganz answered. 500 error is an internal server error. There is probably an invalid character or some other syntax error in the configuration file which is hidden by its size but should be obvious if you get the line number where the error occurred.
Look at the log files they may help pin point the problem.

If the log files don't show anything helpful you might try to zero in on the problem with manual binary search:

- Split the configuration in two.
- Load the first half into the server and see if the problem is there, if not load the second half.
- Rinse and repeat with until you find the error.

There may be more than one error so you may have to repeat the process.

Comment: could duplicate redirects cause a 500 error? say 301 redirect old-url http://www.new-url.com/a and at the same time point to page B.. Ive found some messed up codes here

Comment: Yes, it could. The server would not know to which page to redirect. It depends on the server, whether it validates the configuration or just uses the first redirect. Redirect loops (A -> B -> A) could also be a problem, but I don't know whether they are checked. You should specify the name of the server and add it as a tag to attract more knowledgeable responses.

Comment: I did what you said, sliced up the code until I narrowed it down to just 300 lines, found out I missed to make space between old url and new on two lines.. Now its working fine.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

the error 500 its a server side error, probably something about your code, syntax or something that needs to be compiled (read) on the server, you should keep and eye on the logs of your app server (apache, tomcat or other u are using) and check whats going on...